# Embed a specific section in wordpress site from a live website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, css, embedded-resource

Now i am working in a wordpress website. My target is embedding only fixture as the image from below link,

http://full-time.thefa.com/ListPublicFixture.do?selectedFixtureGroupKey=&selectedRelatedFixtureOption=1&selectedClub=&selectedTeam=&selectedFixtureDateStatus=&selectedFixtureStatus=&selectedDateCode=all&previousSelectedFixtureGroupKey=&previousSelectedClub=4600747&seasonID=441147849&selectedSeason=441147849

. i have done it by using this code.

```
<div id="container">
<iframe id="embed" src="http://full-time.thefa.com/ListPublicFixture.do?divisionseason=452634486&league=8880379" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

```
div#container{
width:1000px !important;
height:330px;
overflow:hidden; 
-webkit-resize:none; 
-moz-resize:none;
resize:none;
position: relative;
```

}

It is okay but problem happen when i select the any team for target link and copy the new link for embedding this new fixture. Problem is " showing extra area with fixture because my iframe container height is fixed.
Now i want to do something for my idea.
idea is: i don't want to change css style, it will fixed. just i replace the embed link in iframe to show the new fixture with its own height with responsive and without showing any extra area.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uF3T.png)

Comment: another code is iframe#embed{
    width:100%;      
    height:2000px;     
    margin: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-resize:none;
    -moz-resize:none;
    resize:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -420px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

Comment: What you are attempting to do is borderline legal at best but is most likely theft of bandwidth and plagiarism. If you want that information on your site you need to write your own tables with your own information or find an open API to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But is it possible to get API or JSON access to gain the target form this link? only for learning the technique.

Comment: Actually it is my client order and this site his own. He order me to do that. i have done this using above code but it is not helpful for him. He want to show this fixture on his new wp site. have any way to do this using this link? please help me if have any way using this link....Thanks for your time.

Comment: In that case build an api. iframes have so many security protocols protecting them from changes you are pretty much stuck with whatever you get. If this site is owned by the client then set up a json api to present the data directly from the db.

Comment: Best solution. can you give me any refarrence link to do setup json on that site.

Comment: Depends which language the source site is in. If it's php wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/. If it's raw php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: Thanks for giving me your valuable time.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't do more. Your question is too broad for a simple solution.